# Compiling a Delegate with Expression.Lambda() - Parameter Out Of Scope, but is it really?

Tags: linq, lambda, compilation, invalidoperationexception

I came across an interesting problem today whilst implementing a feature into a dynamic expression building library. More specifically, but irrelevantly, a feature to define operator precedence in an expression.

When the LINQ engine was compiling the final expression, I was encountering a `InvalidOperationException` declaring `Lambda parameter out of scope`.

The problem manifests itself after assigning the relevant `ParameterExpression` objects.

Working with a complete and well formed lambda expression tree, I discovered that reassigning the Lambda's `ParameterExpression` objects to valid references was invalid when compiling the Lambda.

This is a short description of the behaviour I initially employed before I applied a fix:

- Build the expression tree, destined for use with `Queryable.Where`, the root expression being a `LambdaExpression`, constructed using `Expression.Lambda(expression, Expression.Parameter(GetType(type), "name"))`
- Visit the expression tree (using LinqKit), build hash table of parameters encountered
- Subsequent parameters of the same name are substituted with the first parameter encountered of identical name

The result was an expression tree whereby all the `ParameterExpression` references of the same name were all pointing to the same object- but the `InvalidOperationException` was encountered when compiling.

The fix I applied employed the following behaviour:

- Build the parameters as an array of `ParameterExpression`
- Construct the root Lambda, using `Expression.Lambda(expression, parameterArray)`
- Visit the expression tree (using LinqKit), substitute parameters encountered with parameters from `parameterArray`

The end result compiles fine, even though the Lambda expression structure *is conceptually the same* as the output from the former behaviour.

The question is: **Why does the first fail, and the second succeed**?

Below is a test fixture class to reproduce (excuse the vb), with the test cases and a couple of supporting classes (depends on nUnit, LinqKit):

*note: TestFixture & Test attribute declarations are missing- how to do in markdown???*

```
Imports LinqKit
Imports NUnit.Framework
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

 _
Public Class ParameterOutOfScopeTests

    Public Class TestObject
        Public Name As String
        Public DateOfBirth As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Public DateOfDeath As DateTime?
    End Class

    Public Class ParameterNormalisation
        Inherits ExpressionVisitor

        Public Sub New(ByVal expression As Expression)
            _expression = expression
        End Sub

        Private _expression As expression
        Private _parameter As ParameterExpression
        Private _name As String

        Public Function Normalise(ByVal parameter As ParameterExpression) As Expression
            _parameter = parameter
            _name = parameter.Name
            _expression = Me.Visit(_expression)
            Return _expression
        End Function

        Public Function Normalise(ByVal name As String) As Expression
            _name = name
            _expression = Me.Visit(_expression)
            Return _expression
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Function VisitParameter(ByVal p As System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression) As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

            Debug.WriteLine("ClientExpressionParameterNormalisation.VisitParameter:: Parameter visited: " & p.Name & " " & p.GetHashCode)
            If p.Name.Equals(_name) Then

                If _parameter Is Nothing Then
                    _parameter = p
                    Debug.WriteLine("ClientExpressionParameterNormalisation.VisitParameter:: Primary parameter identified: " & p.GetHashCode)
                ElseIf Not p Is _parameter Then
                    Debug.WriteLine("ClientExpressionParameterNormalisation.VisitParameter:: Secondary parameter substituted: " & p.GetHashCode & " with " & _parameter.GetHashCode)
                    Return MyBase.VisitParameter(_parameter)
                Else
                    Debug.WriteLine("ClientExpressionParameterNormalisation.VisitParameter:: Parameter already common: " & p.GetHashCode & " with " & _parameter.GetHashCode)
                End If

            End If

            Return MyBase.VisitParameter(p)

        End Function


    End Class

     _
    Public Sub Lambda_Parameter_Out_Of_Scope_As_Expected()

        Dim treeOne As Expression(Of Func(Of TestObject, Boolean)) = Function(test As TestObject) test.DateOfBirth > Now And test.Name.Contains("name")
        Dim treeTwo As Expression(Of Func(Of TestObject, Boolean)) = Function(test As TestObject) Not test.DateOfDeath.HasValue

        Dim treeThree As Expression = Expression.And(treeOne.Body, treeTwo.Body)

        Dim realParameter As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(TestObject), "test")

        Dim lambdaOne As LambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(treeThree, realParameter)
        Dim delegateOne As [Delegate] = lambdaOne.Compile

    End Sub

     _
    Public Sub Lambda_Compiles()

        Dim treeOne As Expression(Of Func(Of TestObject, Boolean)) = Function(test As TestObject) test.DateOfBirth > Now And test.Name.Contains("name")
        Dim treeTwo As Expression(Of Func(Of TestObject, Boolean)) = Function(test As TestObject) Not test.DateOfDeath.HasValue

        Dim treeThree As Expression = Expression.And(treeOne.Body, treeTwo.Body)

        Dim normaliser As New ParameterNormalisation(treeThree)
        Dim realParameter As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(TestObject), "test")
        treeThree = normaliser.Normalise(realParameter)

        Dim lambdaOne As LambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(treeThree, realParameter)
        Dim delegateOne As [Delegate] = lambdaOne.Compile

    End Sub

     _
    Public Sub Lambda_Fails_But_Is__Conceptually__Sound()

        Dim treeOne As Expression(Of Func(Of TestObject, Boolean)) = Function(test As TestObject) test.DateOfBirth > Now And test.Name.Contains("name")
        Dim treeTwo As Expression(Of Func(Of TestObject, Boolean)) = Function(test As TestObject) Not test.DateOfDeath.HasValue

        Dim treeThree As Expression = Expression.And(treeOne.Body, treeTwo.Body)

        Dim realParameter As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(TestObject), "test")
        Dim lambdaOne As LambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(treeThree, realParameter)

        Dim normaliser As New ParameterNormalisation(lambdaOne)
        lambdaOne = DirectCast(normaliser.Normalise("test"), LambdaExpression)

        Dim delegateOne As [Delegate] = lambdaOne.Compile

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK expression trees don't consider two ParameterExpression objects created with identical arguments as "the same parameter".

Without having tested your code, then, that's what sticks out: as I read the first (failing) scenario, you replace all same-named parameters with the first such encountered, but that first encountered parameter *is not the same ParameterExpression object* as the one you create in your call to Expression.Lambda(). In the second (succeeding) scenario, it is.

**EDITED** I should add that I haven't used LinqKit's ExpressionVisitor, but as far as I'm aware it's based on code that I have used, in which VisitLambda is not very robust:

```
    protected virtual Expression VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
    {
        Expression body = this.Visit(lambda.Body);
        if (body != lambda.Body)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda(lambda.Type, body, lambda.Parameters);
        }
        return lambda;
    }
```

Note that the body of the expression is visited, but not its parameters. If LinqKit hasn't improved this, that would be the point of failure.

Comment: Indeed, in the successful scenario that is indeed the case- the parameters used in the creation of the lambda expression are the ones used in substitution of all matching parameters elsehwere in the expression, and it compiles.

On a second visit to the expression tree, I verified that the parameter expressions in the first scenario all point to the intended references (inc. the lambda's parameters): conceptually, the expression trees are the same.

It's almost if the lambda expression retains an internal reference to it's original parameters.

Comment: So, in your usage above, LinqKit's ExpressionVisitor correctly visits & replaces the lambda's parameters, and not just those referenced in its body?

Comment: Actually- on reflection- I haven't verified that. But I shall ... and correct the behaviour by extension if that's the case, and retry. I shall report back tomorrow :)

Comment: Infact I just checked the source ala http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/LinqKitSource.zip, and yes! You are correct!

Excellent find, thanks for your input!